# Extracting Keys from a JSONObject using keySet()

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to extract the keys from a JSON Object. The JSON object, in this case, is obtained by making an API call to a social networking site called *SkyRock* and looks like this :

```
{
  "max_page": 2,
  "posts":  {
    "3111623007":  {
      "id_post": 3111623007,
      "media_align": "float_left",
      "tags":  [],
      "nb_comments": 24
    },
    "3114564209":  {
      "id_post": 3114564209,
      "media_align": "float_left",
      "tags":  [],
      "nb_comments": 33
    },
    "3116902311":  {
      "id_post": 3116902311,
      "media_align": "float_left",
      "tags":  [],
      "nb_comments": 29
    }
  }
}
```

I basically want to store all the **post_id** values in an ArrayList. In order to do this, am trying to extract the **keys** from the JSON object and am doing this as follows:

```
JSONObject posts = (JSONObject) jo.get("posts");
ArrayList<String> keys = (ArrayString<String>) posts.keyset();
```

The problem is that am not able to find a suitable variable type in which I can store the result obtained from the **keyset()** method.

I tried searching for the answers, but in most of the cases, **keys()** is being used to extract the keys (which am not able to use for some reason and I think it's maybe because am using org.json.simple, but am not sure).

Can anyone please help me out here to find a solution to the problem or any alternate method to retrieve the Key values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[The javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) says:

```
public interface JsonObject
extends JsonStructure, Map<String,JsonValue>
```

So, a JSONObject is a Map whose keys are of type `String`, and whose values are of type `JSONValue`.

And the [javadoc of `Map<K, V>.keySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) says:

```
Set<K> keySet()

Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map
```

So, what `JSONObject.keySet()` returns is a `Set<String>` (which is quite logical, since keys of JSON objects are strings).

So all that you want is:

```
Set<String> keys = posts.keySet();
```

Comment: However, it's giving some type safety warning. :/

Comment: @RahilArora: I realize my answer links to the javadoc of a class that you're not actually using. Which library does your JSONObject come from?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that! I am using [JSON.simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/).

Comment: is `javax.json.JsonStructure` java 7 only?

Comment: OP asked for JSONObject not JsonObject

Answer (score 11):

The `posts` represents `Map` of `JSONObject` where `key` is `String`

```
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

JSONObject posts = mainObject.getJSONObject("posts");

Map<String, JSONObject> map = (Map<String,JSONObject>)posts.getMap();

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());

System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[3116902311, 3114564209, 3111623007]
```

Comment: Why cast it to a `Map<String, JSONObject>`? It's a `Map<String, JSONValue>`.

Comment: @JBNizet Because `{
      "id_post": 3111623007,
      "media_align": "float_left",
      "tags":  [],
      "nb_comments": 24
    }` represents `JSONObject`. My example works fine and I get all data

Comment: You should cast the JSONValue to a JSONObject, and not the map itself. But it's irrelevant anyway, since the OP wants the keys and not the values of the map.

Comment: well, 1st off my compiler doesn't recognize `JSONValue`. ANd I don't know where to take it. Further, Im sure 100% OP needs keys to allow to extract data because each key is unique: `I basically want to store all the post_id values in an ArrayList`

Comment: @JBNizet and we get `obj.getLong("id_post")` where `obj` is `JSONObject`

Comment: I realize I'm talking about a different JsonObject from the one you and the OP are talking about. I'll remove my downvote and answer.

Comment: The OP doesn't care about id_post. He just wants the keys of the `posts` object.

Comment: @JBNizet true, you are right, changed my answer to store keys to list

Answer (score 7):

This works for me

o is a JSONObject -> import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

```
Set<?> s =  o.keySet();

    Iterator<?> i = s.iterator();
    do{
        String k = i.next().toString();
        System.out.println(k);

    }while(i.hasNext());
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive methods for extracting keys from json objects and arrays (in case of duplicates will merge them since methods return Set, but not Array)

```
public static Set<String> getAllKeys(JSONObject json) {
    return getAllKeys(json, new HashSet<>());
}

public static Set<String> getAllKeys(JSONArray arr) {
    return getAllKeys(arr, new HashSet<>());
}

private static Set<String> getAllKeys(JSONArray arr, Set<String> keys) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        Object obj = arr.get(i);
        if (obj instanceof JSONObject) keys.addAll(getAllKeys(arr.getJSONObject(i)));
        if (obj instanceof JSONArray) keys.addAll(getAllKeys(arr.getJSONArray(i)));
    }

    return keys;
}

private static Set<String> getAllKeys(JSONObject json, Set<String> keys) {
    for (String key : json.keySet()) {
        Object obj = json.get(key);
        if (obj instanceof JSONObject) keys.addAll(getAllKeys(json.getJSONObject(key)));
        if (obj instanceof JSONArray) keys.addAll(getAllKeys(json.getJSONArray(key)));
    }

    keys.addAll(json.keySet());
    return keys;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> here you can create json object then retrieve key using  jsonOject.keys() and you get iterator of here we use  jsonOject.keys() for dynamic keys if you have static key then you know about name of key but if you don't know about key then use this method

```
    val mainObject = JSONObject(jsonString)
    val posts = mainObject.getJSONObject("posts")
    var list = ArrayList<Objects>()
    val map = posts.keys()
    while (map.hasNext()) {
        var key = map.next().toString()
        var jsonObject = posts.getJSONObject(key)
        val gson = Gson()
        val kk: Objects = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), Objects::class.java)
        list.add(kk)
        Log.e("key", key)
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and explain the code.

Answer (score -2):

## My JSONOject is jsonOject;

```
  Iterator <String> listKEY = jsonOject.keys();
                do {
              String newKEY = listKEY.next().toString();
                   
                }while (listKEY.hasNext());
```

Comment: Hi, could you add a little bit information about your answer, this does not tell anything.