# How to get JSON Object Value at 0 position?

Tags: java, json

I have a json object like

> {"0":"Andrew Smith"}

how  can i get the value means **Andrew Smith**. I tried a lot but not getting.They key name will get change. I tried in this way

```
JsonObject jObject = new JsonObject(currentObj);
            System.out.println(currentObj.toString());
            Iterator i = jObject.keys();
            String value = "";
            while(i.hasNext()) {
                String currentKey = String.valueOf(i.next());
                Object currentValue = jObject.get(currentKey);
            }
```

its not going into the loop. So how can i get the value at 0th position.

please help me. Thanks

Comment: What does the println print?

Comment: please check this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195492/extracting-keys-from-a-jsonobject-using-keyset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/):

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new Gson().fromJson("{\"0\":\"Andrew Smith\"}", new TypeToken<Map<Integer, String>>(){}.getType());
System.out.println(map.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue());
```

Prints 'Andrew Smith'.

Comment: I need one more help sir. I have 2 json object one is

{"0":"Andrew Smith","1":"Bob Kline","2":"Bob Kline","3":"Amber Smith","4":"Amber Smith","5":"Andrew Smith","6":"Amber Smith","7":"Eric Smith"}

{"0":"users/media","1":"users/{user-id}"}

Now i want to merge these two means it should me like this .. 

{"users/media":"Andrew Smith","users/media":"Bob Kline","users/{user-id}":"Bob Kline","users/{user-id}":"Amber Smith","users/media":"Amber Smith","users/media":"Andrew Smith","users/{user-id}":"Amber Smith","users/media":"Eric Smith"}

Comment: sure sir ... I know key must be unique. But i will get keys diff in both json object. But i want 1st json object values as key in 3rd json and 2nd json object values as values .. bcz name will always come unique where user/user-id can come multiple time .. hope you got what i want to say :)

Comment: Please provide a rule for the association. And I see replays in result no matter what to use as keys. May want this option: {"Andrew Smith":{"users/media","users/{user-id}"},{"Bob Kline":{"users/media"}"},... ?

Comment: Edits to my previous comment: {"Andrew Smith":{"users/media","users/{user-id}"},"Bob Kline":{"users/media"}",...

Answer (score 0):

Get the iterator for keys and call getString for the first value

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{\"0\":\"Andrew Smith\"}");
Iterator<String> x = obj.keys();
if(x.hasNext())
    Log.e("FACEBOOK", obj.getString(x.next()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works if you just fix all compiler errors.

i.e

It's `JSONObject`, not `JsonObject`.

`currentObj`is not in scope. I suppose you cut it out from somewhere where it is
but replacing it with at string literal will make it easier for other people to
test as well as eliminating one possible source of errors.

Fixing those, putting it in a method and declaring the exception made it work just
fine. Assuming whatever code you started with actually does compile I suggest checking
that the JSONObject in question really is what you think it is.