# How to manage and read json array from php in Android

Tags: php, android, arrays, json

I've lots of json array which are formatted in this way:

```
[
   {
      "cod_ent":"953",
      "name_ent":"example1",
      "amb":{
         "15":{
            "cod_amb":"002",
            "name_amb":"Or11"
         },
         "1723":{
            "cod_amb":"00009",
            "name_amb":"P3o1"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

and i'd like to read it correctly in android. I try with this code and i manage to retrieve the first two entries ("cod_ent" and "name_ent") but i'm still not able to manage "amb" sub-array.

```
        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            InputStream pre_json = response.getEntity().getContent();
            json = new JSONObject("{data:"+convertStreamToString(pre_json)+"}");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("data");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject getfromarray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            cod_ent = getfromarray.getString("cod_ent");
            name_ent = getfromarray.getString("name_ent");

            //how to get amb???


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Iterate JSONObject Like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject =getfromarray.getJSONObject("amb")
    Iterator<String> iter = jsonObject.keys();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        String key = iter.next();
        Log.w("Key", key);
        try {
            JSONObject js = jsonObject.getJSONObject(key);

            Log.w("cod_amb", js.getString("cod_amb"));
            Log.w("name_amb", js.getString("name_amb"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can retrieve the content of `amb` with

```
JSONObject amb = getfromarray.optJSONObject("amb");
```

and you don't know the keys in `amb`, you can use `keys()`, to retrieve an `Iterator<String>`, which contains all the keys of `amb`

```
  Iterator<String> ambKeysIterator = amb.keys();
   while(ambKeysIterator.hasNext()) {
       String key = ambKeysIterator.next();
       JSONObject obj = amb.optJSONObject(key);
       if (obj != null) {
             // parse obj
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a JSONObject from another JSONObject.
Your code can be like this-

```
 JSONObject amb =getfromarray.getJSONObject("amb")
```

EDIT:-

Perhaps you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195492/extracting-keys-from-a-jsonobject-using-keyset)

Comment: ok.. and how can i get all the array in this new json object? in the same way with a for loop?

Comment: As I see in the JSON you posted amb is not an array it is having JSONObjects only.

Answer (score 0):

amb is another `JSONObject`. You should access it like so:

```
JSONObject amb = jsonArray.getJSONObject("amb");
JSONObject fifteen = jsonArray.getJSONObject("15");
String cod_amb = fifteen.getString("cod_amb");
```

Comment: I don't know all the label "15", "1723" .. etc etc.. how can i use your code in a for loop?

Answer (score -1):

"amb" is an array. So you should do something like

```
getfromarray.getJSONArray("amb");
```

in order to get a new JsonArray that you will parse again... and so on