# How to access JSON array inside named object?

Tags: android, json, parsing

I'm building an Android app for displaying school timetable, with the JSON data coming from a URL. However the JSON is formatted in a way that the needed arrays are inside a named "lessons" object. How would it be possible to get access to the arrays I need?

```
This is how my JSON looks

{
    "week": "2019-04-01",
    "times": {
        "1": "07:00-08:29",
        "2": "08:30-10:00",
        "3": "10:15-11:45",
        "4": "11:55-14:00",
        "5": "14:10-15:40",
        "6": "15:45-17:15",
        "7": "17:20-18:50",
        "8": "18:55-20:25",
        "9": "20:35-22:05",
        "lunch": "12:40-13:15"
    },
    "lessons": {
        "2019-04-01": [{
                "lesson": "2",
                "start": "08:30",
                "end": "10:00",
                "subject": "PHP",
                "group": "IS117",
                "teacher": "Jane Doe",
                "room": "A-222"
            }
        ]
    },
    "last update": "2019-03-28 17:02:02"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage and read json array from php in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30443467/how-to-manage-and-read-json-array-from-php-in-android)

Comment: Check out this playlist https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4G-aBwXyKPE76VS0FmvpnkItkyyCPg1r , and please do some research before asking some questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code if it may help you.This will return jsonObject inside 2019-04-01 array.

```
new JSONObject("YOUR RESPONSE STRING HERE").getJSONObject("lessons").getJSONArray("2019-04-01").getJSONObject(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("StringFormat");
JSONArray jsonarray = obj.getJSONArray("2019-04-01");

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use the [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library to make life easier for you in case the JSON responses get more complex in the future. It does all the parsing of the JSON to a normal Java object for you.

- First add this dependency in your gradle: 
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
- Then create a java class/es that would represent the expected JSON structure. You can use this [website](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to auto generate the java classes for you. You just copy/pase the JSON and it generates the JAVA code to construct your classes with constructors and getters/setters.
- Then, you can just auto convert your received JSON object into your Java class.

Example:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JavaClass object = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), JavaClass.class);
```

- Then just access anything you want from that java object easily, instead of manually parsing the JSON objects that you receive.

N.B: I would also recommend you to start learning Retrofit networking library after that. It is considered to be a standard nowadays when doing REST API calls.