# Parse JSON tag name and value to map using Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, deserialization, retrofit

I need to parse such kind of JSON:

```
{
"commodities": {
    "39": "GOLD",
    "41": "SILVER",
    "42": "PLATINUM-APR16",
    "85": "SUGAR (11) ",
    "108": "WHEAT",
    "116": "OIL-MAR16 (WTI CRUDE)",
    "130": "CORN ",
    "158": "COFFEE ",
    "180": "ORANGE S.A.",
    "282": "GOLD/JPY",
    "304": "GOLD/EUR",
    "332": "GOLD/TRY",
    "468": "CRB INDEX",
    "508": "COPPER",
    ...and a LOT more...
},
"currencies": {
    "2": "USD/JPY",
    "35": "AUD/USD",
    "38": "USD/ILS",
    ...and a LOT more...
},
```

How is it possible to save this JSON to `Map`? So I could use it like this:

`String value = mapCommodities.get(key);
String value = mapCommodities.get(39) //value equals "GOLD"`

The problem is I don't know how to parse this index tag from JSON as integer value. I think it's needed to write custom `Deserealizer` but not really have an idea how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a custom deserializer

```
public class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<Map<Integer, String>>>{

        @Override
        public List<Map<Integer, String>> deserialize(JsonElement element, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            List<Map<Integer, String>> randomList = new ArrayList<>();
            JsonObject parentJsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
            Map<Integer, String> childMap;
            for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : parentJsonObject.entrySet()){
                childMap = new HashMap<>();
                for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry1 : entry.getValue().getAsJsonObject().entrySet()){
                    childMap.put(Integer.parseInt(entry1.getKey()), entry1.getValue().toString());
                }
                randomList.add(childMap);
            }
            return randomList;
        }
    }
```

use it by

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
            builder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<ArrayList<Map<Integer, String>>>() {}.getType(), new CityListDeserializer());
            Gson gson = builder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create();
            List<Map<Integer, String>> randomList = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(object), new TypeToken<ArrayList<Map<Integer, String>>>() {}.getType());
```

you can use it by

```
randomList.get(index).get(39);
```

If you want the it `Map<Map<Integer, String>>`, that can also be done. Will update that also. But I would't recomment that for very large data set. HashMaps will consume a considerable amount of memory

**EDIT:**

you can do it this way also

```
public class CityListDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>>{

        @Override
        public Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> deserialize(JsonElement element, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> randomList = new HashMap<>();
            JsonObject parentJsonObject = element.getAsJsonObject();
            Map<Integer, String> childMap;
            for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : parentJsonObject.entrySet()){
                childMap = new HashMap<>();
                for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry1 : entry.getValue().getAsJsonObject().entrySet()){
                    childMap.put(Integer.parseInt(entry1.getKey()), entry1.getValue().toString());
                }
                randomList.put(entry.getKey(), childMap);
            }
            return randomList;
        }
    }
```

use it

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
            builder.registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>>() {}.getType(), new CityListDeserializer());
            Gson gson = builder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES).create();
            Map<String, Map<Integer, String>> randomList = gson.fromJson(String.valueOf(object), new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<Integer, String>>>() {}.getType());
```

access the value by

```
randomList.get("commodities").get(39);
```

this will return you GOLD

All this was for normal json parsing. Not sure but I guess just giving the typetoken like I gave will make it work for Retrofit also

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do :)

First convert the response to JSONARRAY using

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("your string");
```

Then you can iterate or because you know the structre of the respobnse you can simply access it like :)

```
JSON commodityJSON = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
JSON currencies = jsonArray.getJSONObject(1);
```

Once you get the JSON objects access it using

```
commodityJSON.getString("39");
commodityJSON.getString("41");
```

**EDIT**

As per your comment :) You can do something like this i believe :)

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); ++i) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    Iterator<String> objectKeys = jsonObject.keys();
    for( String s : yourKeys){
            System.out.println(jsonObject.getString(s));
    }
}
```

Will it help buddy :) Happy coding buddy :)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But the manual parsing isn't a good solution since there are like thousand of those indexes. Therefore coding every field like this `commodityJSON.getString("39");` would take me forever :D

Comment: So why dont you get all the keys in json and then iterate over it using for loop :D

Comment: That's quite expensive solution. Iteration through json and comparing strings take a lot of time. You see, that list would be iterated a lot of time and it would eat all the resources.

Comment: Have a look at this solution, it might help you :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195492/extracting-keys-from-a-jsonobject-using-keyset

Comment: Yes, that might be helpful using your approach. Let's see if someone can suggest better one. If not, I'll accept your solution

Comment: Yeah :) let's wait :)